# Deleting duplicate relationships in neo4j - is this correct?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have developed a query which, by trial and error, appears to find all of the duplicated relationships in a Neo4j DB. I want delete all but one of these relationships but I'm concerned that I have not thought of problematic cases that could result in data deletion.

So, does this query delete all but one of a duplicated relationship?

```
MATCH (a)-->(b)<--(a)  # identify where the duplication is present
WITH DISTINCT a, b
MATCH (a)-[r]->(b)  # get all duplicated paths themselves
WITH a, b, collect(r)[1..] as rs  # remove the first instance from the list
UNWIND rs as r
DELETE r
```

If I replace the `UNWIND rs as r; DELETE r` with `WITH a, b, count(rs) as cnt RETURN cnt` it seems to return the unnecessary relationships.

I'm still relucant to put this somewhere to be used by others, though....

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, let me (strictly) define the term: "duplicate relationships". Two relationships are duplicates if they:

1. Connect the same pair of nodes (call them `a` and `b`)
2. Have the same relationship type
3. Have exactly the same set of properties (both names and values)
4. Have the same directionality between `a` and `b` (iff directionality is significant for use case)

Your query only considers #1 and #4, so it generally could delete non-duplicate relationships as well.

Here is a query that will take all of the above into consideration (assuming #4 should be included):

```
MATCH (a)-[r1]->(b)<-[r2]-(a)
WHERE TYPE(r1) = TYPE(r2) AND PROPERTIES(r1) = PROPERTIES(r2)
WITH a, b, apoc.coll.union(COLLECT(r1), COLLECT(r2))[1..] AS rs
UNWIND rs as r
DELETE r
```

[Aggregating functions](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/aggregating/) (like `COLLECT`) use non-aggregated terms as `grouping keys`, so there is no need for the query to perform a separate redundant `DISTINCT a,b` test.

The APOC function [apoc.coll.union](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/overview/apoc.coll/apoc.coll.union/) returns the distinct union of its 2 input lists.